# TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property when trying to make changes for specific users

Tags: typescript, parse-platform

In my Ionic application, I have a page where users can make changes to the information about a city. I want changes to be reflected only onto users who share the same "City" as the last user who edited the information about that city.

For example, User 1 is in Chicago, and makes changes to some information. User 2 also is in the city Chicago, and sees those changes. User 3 lives in New York City and does not see those changes.

However, my implementation of this throws an error, "TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property."

This is my .ts code:

```
let user = Parse.User.current().attributes;

if (user.city = lastEditor.attributes.city) { // this is where the error is

    query.equalTo('objectId', this.selectedCity.objectId);

    query.first((results) => {
        results.set("city",city);
        results.set("state",state);
    .
    .
    .
    etc.
```

I am using Safari if that's relevant. However I got the same error when I ran this on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

You have assigned, not compared. Use `===` to compare, not `=`.

```
if (user.city === lastEditor.attributes.city)
```